# Check box not retain the state

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, checkbox, asp.net-2.0

I have a check box in the webform; it is not retain its state when i click in the back button and again comeback the page using next button.

Comment: Are you creating a checkbox dynamically? Show us your page_load event code.

Comment: OK! In case of **back button of browser** you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ViewStateEnabled=true on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You might be setting the value at page load

Answer (score 0):

Try breakpointing the first asp.net event fired and see what the value of the checkbox is then. If it's what it should be then something else is changing it, if it isn't then you're right, it isn't maintaining state.